# Is there anyway to authenticate a user with Github without redirecting them within the current page?

Tags: github, oauth-2.0

I am looking to allow a user to sign in with github for a website I am creating that will be API driven. However, I am running into a problem that there seems to be no way of authenticating a user and getting their email and name without redirecting them on the current page to github. I have tried to create a popup, but there is no way for me to get the necessary data from the popup, namely an api token to be used for the next calls.

Comment: What technology does your server use? There is almost certainly a good github oauth library you can use.

Comment: @OliviaRuth We are using NodeJS, and have already looked into Passport bu it just doesn't fit the flow of how we would like the application to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question as framed is "use a different grant flow" but your questions tell me you don't understand OAuth grant flows so you may be better served by a lecture on OAuth.

Popups and iframes are specifically designed to prevent code running outside them from fishing out data, because if *you* could do it so could invisible iframes in dodgy ads. Give up on that approach because in the unlikely event that you find a way, browser makers will immediately take steps to prevent your solution from working.

The behaviour you describe sounds to me like *implicit grant flow*.

Here's [a walkthrough of the various ways OAuth2 can work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx).

### Why so many ways?

Implicit grant is a flow that uses redirection to deliberately take control away from your code - which might be compromised or impersonated - and give it to a trusted third party, the OAuth provider: GitHub in this case. You pre-register the point to which control is returned after authentication, the point of which is the token is always given to *your* code.

### Amnesia, popups, and what *was* I doing before we were so rudely interrupted?

There are flows that use popups. Usually this is the *authorisation code grant flow*. Popups are not suitable for mobile devices and this led to the creation of the implicit grant flow.

The usual reason for not liking redirection is the amnesia it causes. The solution is to store app state persistently prior to passing control to the OAuth provider, and to write a return-from-oauth handler that unpacks the [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) from the redirect parameter and then restores the app state you saved.

### Note to self

If the user is anonymous prior to authentication serialise your state to a string and put it in a cookie or in localStorage.

If the user is *not* anonymous and is authenticating to *elevate* privilege you'll have to send any privileged data to the server and just persist a retrieval token on the browser. You must ensure that retrieval of this state requires both a valid OAuth token and a valid state token, and that it discards the state after honouring a request so that a replay attack will be conspicuous (you'll have to handle the fallout).

Having acquired a valid token you can use it to request profile information from GitHub. A very small amount may already be present in the JWT; you'll probably have the email address that served as a login, but this isn't necessarily the right one for correspondence.

### GitHub OAuth documentation

It appears GitHub only supports code grant auth. That means you have to do the popup/iframe thing. Here's their doco:

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

### Code grant - why?

This flow doesn't give you an encoded token, it gives you a code you can redeem for an encoded token. The idea is that when the token expires you can use the code to get a refresh token without sending credentials over the wire.

Comment: That makes sense to me, and I understand the whole popup is a security problem, I worded the question poorly. Where is the documentation for how to authenticate the use with Github in the various ways described in the OAuth2 article? Or does Github not support all the various ways? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Not only you have a redirection, but starting Dec. 2020, you also have:

> ### [OAuth 2.0 Device Authorization Flow now GA](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-12-04-oauth-2-0-device-authorization-flow-now-ga/)

> GitHub Apps and OAuth Apps now feature GA support for the OAuth 2.0 **[Device Authorization Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8628)**, in addition to the existing Web Application Flow.
>
> This allows any CLI client or developer tool to [authenticate using a secondary system with a browser](https://github.com/login/device).
> GitHub CLI uses this authentication method on the [login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) command.
>
> Read the full documentation on [Authorizing OAuth Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#device-flow) and [Authorizing Users for GitHub Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps#device-flow) for more information.

---

Confirmed March 2022:

> ### [Enable OAuth Device Authentication Flow for Apps](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-16-enable-oauth-device-authentication-flow-for-apps/)
>
> From today the OAuth Device Authorization flow feature must be manually enabled for all OAuth and GitHub Apps.
>
> This change reduces the likelihood of Apps being used in phishing attacks against GitHub users by ensuring integrators are aware of the risks and make a conscious choice to support this form of authentication.
>
> If you own or manage an OAuth App or GitHub App that makes use of the OAuth Device Authorization flow, you can enable it for your App via its settings page:
>
> [image: Enable device flow]
>
> The OAuth Device Authorization flow API endpoints will respond with status code 400 to Apps that have not enabled this feature.

Documentation: "[Device flow](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#device-flow)"